# Issue with factorial output

Tags: php, factorial

i wann to see factorial output from 1 to 10 . But for this i have to put print code 'echo' in loop . In out side of loop it is  only showing factorial of 10 . here is my code .  Help me to know why 'echo' is not working properly outside the loop.Thanks in advance for help.

[image: here is picture of coding]

```
$factorial = 1;
for ($n = 1; $n <= 10; $n++) {
    $factorial *= $n;

    echo "$factorial \n";

}
echo PHP_EOL;

$factorial = 1;
for ($n = 1; $n <= 10; $n++) {
    $factorial *= $n;

}

echo "$factorial \n";
```

Comment: What don't you understand? If you echo each time through the loop, you see all the intermediate values. If you echo after the loop, you just get the last one.

Comment: Statements execute in order. If an echo statement is outside the loop, it only runs once.

Comment: now i understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo during looping will output each value during each iteration (that means the old data will be replaced by new ones). If you echo outside (below) the loop it will just display the value of the last iteration. 
To overcome your current problem you will need to capture all values into array and later print out in any way you require.

Your original code

```
$factorial = 1;
for ($n = 1; $n <= 10; $n++) {
  $factorial *= $n;
}
echo "$factorial \n";
```

Try using array like this

```
$captureData = [];
$factorial = 1;
for ($n = 1; $n <= 10; $n++) {
    $factorial *= $n;
    $captureData[] = $factorial;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($captureData);
echo '</pre>';
```